# vbscript dictonary problem

Tags: vbscript

I am using dictonary in VBscript. I have some problems that I don't understand some of the behaviour:

```
Dim CmdData  
Set CmdData = CreateObject("System.Dictonary")  
CmdData.Add "11", "tttzz"  
CmdData.Add "sssid", "KRN"  
WScript.Echo(" ZZZZZZZZ= " & CmdData.Count)  'It prints zero and not 2

Dim s  
s = CmdData.Item("11")  
alert(s)  
WScript.Echo(s)   'It prints empry box and not tttzz

Dim a, j   
a = CmdData.Keys  
For j = 0 To CmdData.Count -1  
    WScript.Echo(" ZZZZZZZZ= " & CmdData.Count)   
    WScript.Echo(a(j)) ' doesn not print  
Next  

If (CmdData.Exists("-ad")) Then   
    'WScript.Echo (" RR ") ' It prints it although not in the dictonary  
End If
```

Thanks

Comment: I've never heard of a `System.Dictonary` component.  Is that a custom component?  Typically, `Scripting.Dictionary` is what people use with VBScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBScript's Dictionary is "Scripting.Dictionary":

```
>> set syd = CreateObject("System.Dictionary")
>> syd.add "a",1
>>
Error Number:       429
Error Description:  ActiveX component can't create object
>> set scd = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
>> scd.add "a",1
>> WScript.Echo scd.Count, scd("a")
>>
1 1
```

Comment: Thanks, I have been checking it for 2 hours

Comment: You are welcome. Lately, I spend hours trying to use a "Scripting.FileSystemObject" as a Dictionary. I wonder if you used a global "On Error Resume Next"?